# C program command line argument with spaces

Tags: python, c

My python program `program.py` prints text with spaces, and my C program `a.out` is only expecting a single command line argument.  Why is there different behavior between these two methods... i.e. why does Method 1 work and not Method 2?

Method 1:

```
# program.py
print("Hello world")
```

Terminal:

```
> ./a.out "$(python program.py)"
// Program successfully run
```

Method 2:

```
# program.py
print("\"Hello world \"")
```

Terminal:

```
> ./a.out $(python program.py)
// Error- only one command line argument expected
```

Comment: ...because your command line shell interprets `$` and `(` and `)` as part of the command, not part of a single string argument. Using `"` around your command line argument like you did first is correct.

Comment: Very interesting. In the second case you get the first agument `"Hello` and the second `world "`. It seems that bash ignores quotes and escape characters when reparsing result of `$()`.

Answer (score 0):

> ## Method 1:
>
> `./a.out "$(python program.py)"`

./a.out will use "$(python program.py)" as a string

`echo "$(python program.py)"
prints "$(python program.py)"`

> ## Method 2:
>
> `./a.out $(python program.py)`

./a.out will use the result of $(python program.py) as an argument.

`echo $(python program.py)`
will run the program, and what is printed will be used as an argument.
Because you have printed `Hello world`, it will use Hello as the first argument, and world as the second argument.
it will result in something like
`./a.out Hello World`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently whenever you use a $something, it will always be split in several parameters if you have spaces in it.
Just look at how $1 works, it's the same behavior.
Then your $(command) will work the same.
This is why you have to put quotes around it.

I tried:

```
ls $(echo '"Hello World!"')
```

It has the same behavior than your second method.

And this:

```
ls "$(echo 'Hello World!')"
```

Is the same than your first method.